# Handling multiple elements with same id value does not work

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, materialize

I want to have drop-down menu on each list item as shown:

[image: drop-down menu]

my code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="card white">
  <div class="card-content grey-text text-darken-4">
    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title</span>
      <a id="myDropdown" class='btn-floating waves-effect waves-light transparent right' href='#' data-activates='myDropdown-menu'><i class="material-icons blue-grey-text text-darken-4">more_vert</i></a>
      <ul id='myDropdown-menu' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card white">
  <div class="card-content grey-text text-darken-4">
    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title</span>
      <a id="myDropdown" class='btn-floating waves-effect waves-light transparent right' href='#' data-activates='myDropdown-menu'><i class="material-icons blue-grey-text text-darken-4">more_vert</i></a>
      <ul id='myDropdown-menu' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#myDropdown").dropdown();
```

now the issue is if I use `id="myDropdown"` on more than one elements it only works with first item other menus are not functioning correctly. How can I solve this.

here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04cnz8gt/) for this as demo.

Please suggest me the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The id must be unique. Using the same id twice is thus an error.

Answer (score 0):

An 'id' as its name suggests, is a unique identifier for an element in the dom. Make sure that your IDs are unique and never use the same id for more than one element. If you need something to identity a group of elements, use a class.

Answer (score 0):

An id, is an name given to an element which has its own style and function, and cannot be applied to an element which also needs that same function. If there are many elements that have that same style and function, use 'class'. An id can only get applied once. Here is the documentation: [https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_id.asp#:~:text=%20HTML%20id%20Attribute%20%201%20Using%20The,for%20that...%206%20Chapter%20Summary.%20%20More%20](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_id.asp#:%7E:text=%20HTML%20id%20Attribute%20%201%20Using%20The,for%20that...%206%20Chapter%20Summary.%20%20More%20)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. When answering a question, please check existing answers first. Duplicating an existing answer, creates a poor user experience.